# vbscript, validate a user is in active directory by schema attribute

Tags: vbscript, active-directory, schema

I'm trying to write a vb script that prompts a user for a schema attribute which I'll call bID and checks that the person with that bID is in active directory.  I really have no idea how to get started, there are plenty of examples on how to query active directory users but I havent found a good one regarding checking against specific attributes.  Any help/suggestions are greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
ok heres my code so far, doesnt error out and returns 0, but I dont get a wscript.echo of the distinguished name for some reason.  I included a few debugging wscript.echo's and it seems to never get into the while loop.  Any ideas?

```
Option Explicit

GetUsers "CN=users,DC=example,DC=example,DC=example,DC=com","123456"

Function GetUsers(domainNc, ID)
    Dim cnxn    
    Set cnxn = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")    
    cnxn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"    
    cnxn.Open "Active Directory Provider"    
    Dim cmd    
    Set cmd = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")    
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnxn    
    cmd.CommandText = "<LDAP://" & domainNc & ">;(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)    (employeeNumber=" & ID & "));distinguishedName;subtree"
    WScript.Echo cmd.CommandText
    cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 100    
    cmd.Properties("Timeout") = 30    
    cmd.Properties("Cache Results") = False    
    WScript.Echo "setting cmd.properties"
    Dim rs
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    WScript.Echo "rs object set"
    While Not rs.eof
        On Error Resume Next
        WScript.Echo "while loop start"
        Wscript.Echo rs.fields("distinguishedName".Value)
        rs.MoveNext
        If (Err.Number <> 0) Then       
     WScript.Echo vbCrLf& "Error # "& CStr(Err.Number)& " "& Err.Description
        Else
      On Error GoTo 0
        End If 
    Wend
    WScript.Echo "while loop end"
    rs.close    
    WScript.Echo "rs object closed"
    cnxn.Close    
    Set rs = Nothing    
    Set cmd = Nothing    
    Set cnxn = Nothing 
    End Function
```

Comment: Hey guys, the above script runs without an error (returns 0) but I never get any wscript.echos from inside the while loop, any ideas?

Comment: The syntax is wrong. Change the line to this:     Wscript.Echo rs.fields("distinguishedName").Value

Answer (score 0):

Here's some vbscript that will find all users with bID=FooVal and write their DN out

```
Function GetUsers(domainNc, bIdVal)
    Dim cnxn
    Set cnxn = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnxn.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    cnxn.Open "Active Directory Provider"

    Dim cmd
    Set cmd = WScript.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cnxn

    cmd.CommandText = "<LDAP://" & domainNc & ">;(&(objectCass=user)(objectCategory=person)(bid=" & bidVal & "));distinguishedName;subtree"
    cmd.Properties("Page Size") = 100
    cmd.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    cmd.Properties("Cache Results") = False

    Dim rs
    Set rs = cmd.Execute

    While Not rs.eof 
        Wscript.Echo rs.fields("distinguishedName").Value

        rs.MoveNext
    Wend 

    rs.close
    cnxn.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing
    Set cnxn = Nothing 
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks brian for your response!  I've modified domainNc to contain our DC information but it returns: `(32, 5) Provider: A referral was returned from the server.`  Could that mean I have our DC information wrong or maybe the attribute type is wrong?  Are attriute types case-sensitive?

Comment: Hey brian thanks for your help so far, I'm so close I can feel it! I updated the code up top and it seems to work (returns 0) but I never get a wscript.echo of the distinguished name, any ideas?